# Issue Passing Query Parameters to Report - Text Params Work, Date Params Don't

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, parameters

So I have the following query (relevant parts only):

```
Private Sub Search_Button_Click()

DoCmd.SetParameter "[FromForm_Bldg]", Nz([Forms]![MAIN MENU]!FromForm_Bldg.Value, "")
DoCmd.SetParameter "[FromForm_Associate]", Nz([Forms]![MAIN MENU]!FromForm_Associate.Value, "")
DoCmd.SetParameter "[FromForm_StartDate]", "'" & [Forms]![MAIN MENU]!FromForm_StartDate & "'"
DoCmd.SetParameter "[FromForm_EndDate]", "'" & [Forms]![MAIN MENU]!FromForm_EndDate & "'"

DoCmd.OpenReport "ALL MOVES", acViewReport, , , , "[FromForm_Bldg]=" & Param1 & "|" & "D2=" & Param2
```

End Sub

And this Access SQL Query:

```
PARAMETERS
[FromForm_Bldg] Text ( 255 ),
[FromForm_Associate] Text ( 255 ),
[FromForm_StartDate] DateTime,
[FromForm_EndDate] DateTime;

SELECT
Max(QUERY_BY_TOTAL.ACT_DATE) AS ACT_DATE,
Max(QUERY_BY_TOTAL.BLDG) AS BLDG,
QUERY_BY_TOTAL.ASSOCIATE AS ASSOCIATE,

FROM
QUERY_BY_TOTAL

WHERE
(((QUERY_BY_TOTAL.BLDG)=[FromForm_Bldg])
AND ((QUERY_BY_TOTAL.ACT_DATE)>=[FromForm_StartDate] And (QUERY_BY_TOTAL.ACT_DATE) <=[FromForm_EndDate])
AND ((QUERY_BY_TOTAL.ASSOCIATE)=[FromForm_Associate])) OR (((QUERY_BY_TOTAL.ACT_DATE)>=[FromForm_StartDate] And (QUERY_BY_TOTAL.ACT_DATE)<=[FromForm_EndDate])
AND ((QUERY_BY_TOTAL.ASSOCIATE)=[FromForm_Associate])
AND (([FromForm_Bldg]) Is Null)) OR (((QUERY_BY_TOTAL.BLDG)=[FromForm_Bldg])
AND ((QUERY_BY_TOTAL.ACT_DATE)>=[FromForm_StartDate] And (QUERY_BY_TOTAL.ACT_DATE)<=[FromForm_EndDate])
AND (([FromForm_Associate]) Is Null)) OR (((QUERY_BY_TOTAL.ACT_DATE)>=[FromForm_StartDate] And (QUERY_BY_TOTAL.ACT_DATE)<=[FromForm_EndDate])
AND (([FromForm_Bldg]) Is Null)
AND (([FromForm_Associate]) Is Null))

GROUP BY
QUERY_BY_TOTAL.ASSOCIATE
```

And the report I'm trying to fill in with parameters from my form will not populate with any data, and I'm 99% sure the issue is with the dates, as the vba has no issues with the first 2 parameters but errors out at the first data parameter. I've played with dates and formatting for a week now and I feel so defeated.

That said, I DO have a VBA macro that takes this query data with parameters and puts it all in the body of an email working flawlessly. For reference, here is the email macro:

```
'CREATE TABLE HEADER
    Dim xMailBody As String
    xMailBody = "<TABLE Border=""1"", Cellspacing=""0""><TR>" & _
    "<TD Bgcolor=""#0642a1"", Align=""Center""><Font Color=#FCDFFF><b><p style=""font-size:16px"">BLDG&nbsp;</p></Font></TD>" & _
    "<TD Bgcolor=""#0642a1"", Align=""Center""><Font Color=#FCDFFF><b><p style=""font-size:16px"">ASSOCIATE&nbsp;</p></Font></TD>" & _
    "<TD Bgcolor=""#0642a1"", Align=""Center""><Font Color=#FCDFFF><b><p style=""font-size:16px"">PICKING&nbsp;</p></Font></TD>" & _
    "<TD Bgcolor=""#0642a1"", Align=""Center""><Font Color=#FCDFFF><b><p style=""font-size:16px"">FLOOR MOVES&nbsp;</p></Font></TD>" & _
    "<TD Bgcolor=""#0642a1"", Align=""Center""><Font Color=#FCDFFF><b><p style=""font-size:16px"">LOADOUT&nbsp;</p></Font></TD>" & _
    "<TD Bgcolor=""#0642a1"", Align=""Center""><Font Color=#FCDFFF><b><p style=""font-size:16px"">PUTAWAY&nbsp;</p></Font></TD>" & _
    "<TD Bgcolor=""#0642a1"", Align=""Center""><Font Color=#FCDFFF><b><p style=""font-size:16px"">STAGING&nbsp;</p></Font></TD>" & _
    "<TD Bgcolor=""#0642a1"", Align=""Center""><Font Color=#FCDFFF><b><p style=""font-size:16px"">TOTAL&nbsp;</p></Font></TD>" & _
    "</TR>"

'SELECT TABLE DATA
    Dim MyDb As DAO.Database
    Dim Myqdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim MyQueryName As String

    MyQueryName = "DATA_BY_TOTAL"
    Set MyDb = CurrentDb()
    Set Myqdf = MyDb.QueryDefs(MyQueryName)

'SET PARAMETER VALUES
    Myqdf.Parameters("[FromForm_Bldg]") = Nz([Forms]![MAIN MENU]!FromForm_Bldg.Value, "")
    Myqdf.Parameters("[FromForm_Associate]") = Nz([Forms]![MAIN MENU]!FromForm_Associate.Value, "")
    Myqdf.Parameters("[FromForm_StartDate]") = [Forms]![MAIN MENU]!FromForm_StartDate
    Myqdf.Parameters("[FromForm_EndDate]") = [Forms]![MAIN MENU]!FromForm_EndDate

    Set rs = Myqdf.OpenRecordset()
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rs.EOF

    'LOOP THROUGH COLUMNS TO CREATE TABLE
        xMailBody = xMailBody & "<TR>" & _
        "<TD><center>" & rs.Fields![ACT_DATE].Value & "</TD>" & _
        "<TD><center>" & rs.Fields![ASSOCIATE].Value & "</TD>" & _
        "<TD><center>" & rs.Fields![PK].Value & "</TD>" & _
        "<TD><center>" & rs.Fields![FM].Value & "</TD>" & _
        "<TD><center>" & rs.Fields![LO].Value & "</TD>" & _
        "<TD><center>" & rs.Fields![AW].Value & "</TD>" & _
        "<TD><center>" & rs.Fields![IS].Value & "</TD>" & _
        "<TD><center>" & rs.Fields![TOTAL].Value & "</TD>" & _
        "</TR>"
    
    'END LOOP
        rs.MoveNext
        Loop
```

I cannot for the life of me get the same query data with the same parameters to fill the dang report. I've confirmed the date format of the source/query data is the same as the date input fields on my form, so I have no idea why it's not working.

Help! Please help!

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn’t seem to make a difference. Must have tried 100 different combinations of quotes, apostrophes, # signs, etc., no dice for any of it.

Answer (score 0):

Using string expression for date values will work, and you should force the ISO sequence (yyyy-mm-dd) on these:

```vb
DoCmd.SetParameter "[FromForm_StartDate]", "#" & Format([Forms]![MAIN MENU]!FromForm_StartDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
DoCmd.SetParameter "[FromForm_EndDate]", "#" & Format([Forms]![MAIN MENU]!FromForm_EndDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
```

Also, make sure that *QUERY_BY_TOTAL.ACT_DATE* returns a date value, not formatted text.

Comment: Sincerely appreciate the response, but that still yields an empty report. With the date parameter type in my query set to "Date with Time" the report is empty, so I also tried setting the type to Short Text, which results in the error "The expression is too complex to be evaluated..." :(

Comment: Then check your query (`DoCmd.OpenQuery  ....`). It probably returns no records with the date interval set.

Comment: Changed the VBA to open the query instead of the report and you are correct, it is empty. However, when I open the report from the navigation pane on the left and manually type the parameters in the pop-up windows (and copy/paste the exact date from my form that would otherwise be used in the date parameters) it works perfectly. I don't understand. *bangs head on desk*

Comment: Let the query return `[Forms]![MAIN MENU]!FromForm_EndDate` and the other value and study the output.

Comment: Still no dice. I even used a MsgBox in my VBA to return all the parameter values and they return exactly as they should. Somehow those two date values just aren't getting passed correctly to the query. This is literally a roadblock keeping me from fixing 6 other similar databases that I could really use :(

Comment: The ` the date format of the source/query data` doesn't return a true date value. A date value carries no format.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with this:

```
DoCmd.SetParameter "[FromForm_StartDate]", "#" & Format([Forms]![MAIN MENU]!FromForm_StartDate, "m/d/yyyy 05:00") & "#"
DoCmd.SetParameter "[FromForm_EndDate]", "#" & Format([Forms]![MAIN MENU]!FromForm_EndDate, "m/d/yyyy 04:59") & "#"
DoCmd.SetParameter "[FromForm_Bldg]", [Forms]![MAIN MENU]!FromForm_Bldg.Value
DoCmd.SetParameter "[FromForm_Associate]", [Forms]![MAIN MENU]!FromForm_Associate.Value
```

And by using "Like [ParameterName]" in my query SQL where the parameter value from the form field is "*" when I want the parameter to evaluate as null. So for my actual parameters, this example would pull data for 7/26/21 through 7/27/21 and include all buildings and all users/associates:

[image]

BUT, now I'm stuck because I want to use the same parameters in another query but it's not working. [New question created here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68542893/cannot-pass-parameters-to-multiple-queries).